# How to replace efficiently values on a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I've got a large DataFrame(600k,2) named **data** and basically I have in the second column a set of 50k unique values distributed along the data.

The data looks like this

```
    image_id     term 
0   56127        23001  
1   56127        763003  
2   56127        51002  
3   26947        581007  
4   26947        14001  
5   26947        95000  
6   26947        92000  
7   26947        62004  
8   26947        224007
...600k more
```

On the other hand I have a Series named **terms_indexed** with an index composed of this 50k terms like this.

```
            NewTerm
Term                  
23001          9100
763003          402
51002         10608
581007          900
14001         42107
95000           900
92000          4002
62004         42107
224007         9100
...50k more
```

But I want to reemplace those values in the original DataFrame efficiently using the Series with the indexed terms. So far I have done it with the following line

```
for i in range(data.shape[0]):
        data.loc[i, 'term'] = int(terms_indexed.ix[data.iloc[i][1]])
```

However it takes so much time doing this replacement operation. About 35minutes in an intel core i7 with 8GB ram. I wanted to know if there is a better way to do this operation. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you set the index on `term` column on your large df then you could just call [`update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) like so `large_df.update(other_df)`

Comment: This might be a use case for the shiny categorical dtype (for the term column).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your situation right, you can just do `df['term'] = df['term'].map(terms_indexed)`.  Doing `series1.map(series2)` "translates" series1 by using its values as indexes into series2.

Comment: I just compared `update` against `map` and was a little surprised that `map` outpferformed `update`, for 90k dataframe `update` takes 19.4ms vs 8.61ms for `map`.

Comment: The reason I say this is that Jeff has always commented to me that `map` and `apply` are last resort methods so I thought `update` would perform better

Comment: @EdChum: I think `map` with a function argument can be slow.  `map` with a series argument should be pretty fast.  But I'm not up on pandas internals so I don't know for sure.

Comment: I think I was told as a comment that map is a cython optimised for loop, not sure if that changes if the datatype is a series. Anyway this was the comment from [Jeff](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25570147/add-new-column-based-on-boolean-values-in-a-different-column/25570219#comment39938300_25570219)

Comment: @EdChum if arg is a Series/dict (and has a unique index), then this is a completely vectorized operation (so very fast); it even better than cython, just a take really.

Comment: @Jeff Ah.. OK thanks for the clarification, appreciate the fact you take the time even to answer these comments.

Comment: I had to interrupt .replace because it took to long, while this solution took about 3 seconds on a dataframe with more than 22000 rows.